# How can I access the variable in model sent by post method from view file in yii?

Tags: javascript, php, post, model-view-controller, yii

I have did the following so far my view file where I am sending my data to model, tariffCardType, jobType, clothType, newRegularRate, newUrgentRate are all JavaScript variables which I have to send as data

tariffcard.php(view)

```
function saveRates(btnId, regularValue, urgentValue)
  {
    var clothType = btnId.substring(0, btnId.indexOf("-"));
    var tariffCardType = btnId.substring(btnId.indexOf("-")+1, btnId.indexOf("-", btnId.indexOf("-")+1));
    var jobTypeCode = btnId.substring(btnId.indexOf("-", btnId.indexOf("-")+1)+1, btnId.length); 
    var jobType = "iron";
    <?php
    echo CHtml::ajax(array(
            'url'=>  CController::createUrl("site/UpdateRates"),
            'type'=>'get',
            'data' => "{tarifftardtype:tariffCardType, jobtype:jobType, clothtype:clothType, newregularrate:newRegularRate, newurgentrate:newUrgentRate}",
            'success'=> "function(html){document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = html;}",
    ))
    ?>
  }
```

I am trying to access the data in model as follow

TariffCardForm.php(model)

```
public function updateTariffRates()
{
    $response["tariffcardtype"] = Yii::$app->request->getPost('tarifftardtype');
    $response["jobtype"] = Yii::$app->request->getPost('jobtype');
    $response["clothtype"] = Yii::$app->request->getPost('clothtype');
    $response["newregularrate"] = Yii::$app->request->getPost('newregularrate');
    $response["newurgentrate"] = Yii::$app->request->getPost('newurgentrate');

    return $response;
}
```

The method I am using is it correct to access the data in model? Also how can I send the javascript variables as a data in php array?

Comment: you're sending data from your view to model? why ?
Also, assuming `saveRates` is a js function you have written a php code inside it, without starting & ending php tags.

Comment: @Criesto I want to send the data to model so that I can update the details in database. `saverates` is a JS function which is called on a click action. php code is written in php tags, I forgot to mention it here.

Comment: Where you are trying to get your get your data should be done in your controller (SiteController, actionUpdateRates) not the model. That way it can be validated and then passed to the TariffCardForm model. Your model tells your controller all was good on the update and controller tells view success.